# Python 3 cgi script doesn't work, but python 2 works

Tags: python, python-3.x, cgi, python-2.x

I'm new to cgi programming :) I have the following python cgi-scripts, one in python2 and the other in python3. The servers works well with the python2 script but it doesn't run the python3 one. python3.2 is installed on the server.

Here is the python2 script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

print "Content-type: text/html"
print ""
print ''' 
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello Word - First CGI Program</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Hello Word! This is my first CGI program</h2>
</body>
</html>'''
```

Here is the python3 script

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.2

print("Content-type: text/html")
print("")
print(''' 
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello Word - First CGI Program</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Hello Word! This is my first CGI program</h2>
</body>
</html>''')
```

Comment: *but it doesn't run the python3 one* Are there no errors in the server log?

Comment: Where should I look for the server log? The server belongs to my university.

Comment: @user2705123 - depends on the server. For apache, try `/var/log/apache2/error.log` (if you have access to that). The code should work, check the permissions of the script, and that `python3.2` really is on the default path (cgi scripts don't source `~/.profile` etc.)

Comment: Did you make the python3 script executable?

Answer (score 1):

The http.server is replaced. python3 -m http.server --cgi 8000